# Linq To Sql returns value length instead of value

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I just started teaching myself Linq to SQL today.  I hardly know anything about linq.  That being said, I have a query that i want to return a Name from my database.  It is a varchar in the DB

```
var query = from a in FRESH.Customers
            select a.CUSTOMER_NAME;

dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
```

This results in a gridview with a column named "Length" and displays the length of every name.  If I change the query to `select a` everything displays fine.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DataGridView` will by default show all of the properties of the type in the list as columns.  Since your query is returning a collection of `string`s and the [only<sup>1</sup> "property"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h75y1h8f.aspx) of a `string` is `Length` it shows that as a column.

Try changing to

```
var query = from a in FRESH.Customers
            select new {Name = a.CUSTOMER_NAME};
```

<sup>1</sup>Technically the indexer `Chars` is a "property" but the `DataGridView` must be clever enough not to use an indexer as a column.

Comment: So why does it work when I select the entire table?  Do you have anywhere to point me for a good tutorial?  Not the MSDN sites, but more of a real-world use

Comment: It works because you're returning a collection of objects which have properties like `CUSTOMER_NAME`.  When you return a collection of strings it's not clever enough to know that you want to show the _strings_ and not their _properties_.

Comment: heh..have been..trust me..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in gridView, not in Linq - gridView looks for properties of objects in `DataSource`. And it binds to first found property. Thus it binds strings by `Length` property (its the only property which `String` object has).

Default approach for displaying strings in gridView is creating some wrapper, which will have property with string value:

```
public class StringValue
{    
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When you create anonymous object, as @DStanley suggested, wrapper is created for you by Linq:

```
var query = from a in FRESH.Customers
            select new { CustomerName = a.CUSTOMER_NAME};
```

GridView will look for properties in anonymous object, and it will find and use `CustomerName` property.

Comment: I disagree, the gridView binds to properties.  Since an array of string only has two properties (Chars and Length) those are all you can bind to.

Comment: @Trisped how it differs from what I wrote? `its the only property which String has`